# Why to use AOP for transaction management in Spring?

Tags: spring, transactions, aop, cross-cutting-concerns

I am learning `AOP` and came to know that is useful for separation of concern, for example, `logging`, `transaction management`, `security` etc.

So far good to know `AOP`.

Now, I read about **Spring transaction management** in Spring framework we can have annotation `@Transactional`.

It is this point which is make me confused why should we use `AOP` in which we have to create `Aspects` rather than using the annotation which Spring provides.

## For example:

```
@Transactional
public void dataAccessTrans() {

}
```

When Spring is already having transaction related functionality, then why should we use `AOP` to do transaction management?

If we use `AOP`, then don't we have to create `Aspect` and create `advice` which would act on the method; **does't this make us to do manual work**, rather than handling it by spring framework itself by its own annotations.

Can anyone help me understand this which I am not able to understand clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) relies on AOP to implement declarative transactions.

> **The Spring Framework’s declarative transaction management is made
>   possible with Spring aspect-oriented programming (AOP)**, although, as
>   the transactional aspects code comes with the Spring Framework
>   distribution and may be used in a boilerplate fashion, AOP concepts do
>   not generally have to be understood to make effective use of this
>   code.

So as you use the `@Transactional` annotation :

```
@Transactional
public void dataAccessTrans() {
  ...
}
```

you use indirectly AOP.
So in the very most of cases, you never need to declare any custom aspects to handle the transaction management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, makes sense. Your reply clarified the doubt, accepting your answer, thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Clever question. And finally you were on the right path :)